# Understanding LD under MSYS2

Tags: build, makefile, ld, avr-gcc

I'm trying to compile the simavr project from https://github.com/buserror/simavr on Windows 10 using MSYS2 and mingw-w64.

After editing the makefiles to enable the MSYS clauses (Which are commented out by default), and changing the order of 2 include files, I can get the project to compile. I do however encounter an error in the linking step.

The output is

```
C:/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsimavr
```

Editing the makefile to print the ${LDFLAGS}, yield the following.

```
-L/lib -L/local/lib -L/c/Users/University/GitHub/simavr/simavr/../simavr/obj-i686-w64-mingw32 -lsimavr -lelf -lws2_32
```

Looking in the folder "obj-i686-w64-mingw32" mentioned in the build script, the file "libsimavr.a" is present. If I copy the file to the msys lib folder the linking step works fine.

The folder structure of the project is as follows:

- simavr root (Where i run the makefile from, located in /c/Users/University/GitHub)

  - simavr

    - obj-i686-w64-mingw32

As far as I can tell, LD should be able to link properly without me copying the file manually. What am I missing here?

**Edit:**

The final command before the linker error.

```
cc -MMD -Werror -O2 -Wall -g -I/usr/local/include -DNO_COLOR   -o obj-i686-w64-mingw32/run_avr.elf obj-i686-w64-mingw32/run_avr.o -L/lib -L/local/lib -L/c/Users/University/GitHub/simavr/simavr/../simavr/obj-i686-w64-mingw32 -lsimavr  -lelf  -lws2_32
```

**Edit 2:**

Cleaning the include paths of MSYS folders:

```
cc -MMD -Werror -O2 -Wall -g -DNO_COLOR   -o obj-i686-w64-mingw32/run_avr.elf obj-i686-w64-mingw32/run_avr.o -L/c/Users/University/GitHub/simavr/simavr/../simavr/obj-i686-w64-mingw32 -lsimavr  -lelf  -lws2_32
C:/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsimavr
```

Passing CC=gcc to make:

```
gcc -MMD -Werror -O2 -Wall -g -DNO_COLOR   -o obj-i686-w64-mingw32/run_avr.elf obj-i686-w64-mingw32/run_avr.o -L/c/Users/University/GitHub/simavr/simavr/../simavr/obj-i686-w64-mingw32 -lsimavr  -lelf  -lws2_32
C:/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsimavr
```

**Edit 3:**

Output of the find command:

```
$ find /c/Users/University/GitHub/simavr -name 'libsimavr.a'
/c/Users/University/GitHub/simavr/simavr/obj-i686-w64-mingw32/libsimavr.a
```

Note that previous entries have been made using the git bash prompt, not the one from msys2. However, running the same commands in the msys2 prompt or the mingw prompt from msys2 yields the same results.

Comment: The `LDFLAGS` may well be correct be correct but as you have edited the
makefile we cannot be sure that what is done with them is still correct.
To get help with a failing linkage you must post at least the failing
linker command, verbatim as output by `make`, and all the diagnostics
that follow from it. To get this output from the `simavr` make, run it
in verbose mode, `make V=1`. There is no need to edit the makefile for
this. The failing linker command is the final `cc ...` command before
`bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsimavr`. Post it in the body of your question.

Comment: At the MYSY2 prompt, what is the output of the command `find /c/Users/University/GitHub/simavr -name 'libsimavr.a'`?

Comment: `$ find /c/Users/University/GitHub/simavr -name 'libsimavr.a'
/c/Users/University/GitHub/simavr/simavr/obj-i686-w64-mingw32/libsimavr.a`

Answer (score 2):

Using mingw-w64 toolchain to build project you MUST remove from CFLAGS/CXXFLAGS/CPPFLAGS all paths with /usr, /local, /lib, /include as this paths can contain headers and libs from MSYS2 itself. Second, try pass "CC=gcc" to makefile.